# Laravel registration in existing database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have an issue with laravel / sql server.
Need to save, validate, user register on existing database in sql server.
On complete inputs does nothing. and nothing save into database

My table name:  tb_postulantes

Here my files:

--------model USER---------------

`` `

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable

{


    protected $table = 'tb_postulante';


    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre_postulante', 'correo_postulante', 'password_postulante',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password_postulante', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

` ``

--------Register controller--------

`` `

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nombre_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'correo_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);


    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'nombre_empleado' => $data['name'],
            'correo_empleado' => $data['email'],
            'password_empleado' => Hash::make($data['password_empleado']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

` ``

--------view register.blade--------

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @error('name')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="correo_postulante" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="correo_postulante" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="correo_postulante" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Your fillable columns end with `postulante`, you're passing in columns ending in `empleado`

Comment: Yeah, my columns are: id_postulante - nombre_postulante - correo_postulante - password_postulante - created_at - update_at

Comment: You need to pass in the correct column names into your create function. If it can't match the column name, it can't pass it in.

Comment: ` protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'nombre_empleado' => $data['nombre_empleado'],
            'correo_empleado' => $data['correo_empleado'],
            'password_empleado' => Hash::make($data['password_empleado']),
        ]);
    }`

Comment: You mean this right?

Comment: Correct. Keys ending with `empleado` won't match any of the existing columns that end with `postulante`

Comment: I have changed everything and even so, still not saving anything in the database :(

Comment: Your email field in your form is named `correo_postulante`, but you're getting `$data['email']`. Also, your form values do not match what you're expecting in the validator. Try some logging in both functions with `Log::info()` (logs will be written to `storage/logs` to see what's coming through. Such as `Log::info([
            'nombre_empleado' => $data['name'],
            'correo_empleado' => $data['email'],
            'password_empleado' => $data['password_empleado']]);` as the first line of your `create` function.